# Netbeans 7 - how to define the order of the tooldbars

Tags: netbeans, action, toolbar, netbeans-platform, netbeans7.0

i'm trying to change the toolbars order.
before netbeans 7 the order was set according to the layout.xml/
but in netBeans 7 it is all annotation.

Comment: Wish I could help you.  You might try your luck on the NetBean Platform Users forum. http://forums.netbeans.org/platform-users.html

Comment: I've answered a similar question in detail in this link. Generally it is as Tim pointed out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831496/netbeans-7-3-customise-edit-toolbar-positions/17418566#17418566. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the annotations will do is create a layer.xml file for you (At runtime I think).

You can still create your own layer.xml file and change the order of the toolbars in there. Just make sure that your layer file is being referenced in the manifest.

At Runtime all the layers will be merged together - including the one that you manually create and the one derived from the annotations