# Netbeans RCP - Remove unwanted menu items, toolbars, etc

Tags: java, swing, rcp, netbeans-7

I'm sure this is a simple question.  I simply cannot find it for Netbeans 7.  I have created a Netbeans platform application and modules.

how do I customize the `File`, `Edit`, etc menus, and disable the ability to bring up the `Undo` \ `Redo` toolbar?

ALSO: Under Branding, I have specified an icon to use for the application, but upon generating an installer it does not use that icon.  What gives?  When I specify it, does it need to be in some specific directory within the Netbeans project to get packaged with the installer?

Thank you for your help.  I'm sure I've just overlooked something.

Comment: Are you referring to the NB IDE or to a NB Platform Application/Module Suite or some another kind of project?

Comment: To a Netbeans platform application.

Comment: see [this][1] post it might help


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033904/netbeans-7-how-to-define-the-order-of-the-tooldbars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is like netbean 6.9
All the annotations will do is create a layer.xml file for you (At runtime I think).

You can still create your own layer.xml file and change the order of the toolbars in there. Just make sure that your layer file is being referenced in the manifest.

At Runtime all the layers will be merged together - including the one that you manually create and the one derived from the annotations

Comment: For all those that might look here, Adi's answer got me looking around, and I found exactly what I was looking for hidden in the [HTML Editor] (http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/70/nbm-htmleditor.html#tweakingthemenuitems) tutorial.